# Bootstrap dropdown for filtering in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new on Ruby on Rails and I have a problems with rewriting the code. I have a tabs which can be used as filters. Here is the source code

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs groups-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <%= link_to 'All',  "#all", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab" %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <%= link_to 'Python',  "#python", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab" %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="<%= ''%>">
      <%= link_to "Algorithms", "#algorithms", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab"  %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="<%= ''%>">
      <%= link_to "Web", "#web", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab"  %>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content table-responsive" role="tablist">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="all">
        <%= render 'requests',requests: @requests%>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane " id="python">
        <%= render 'requests',requests: @requests.python%>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="algorithms">
        <%= render 'requests',requests: @requests.algorithms%>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="web">
        <%= render 'requests',requests: @requests.web%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now I am trying to rewrite this logic as "Dropdown" component in Bootstrap. It launches without errors, however after the clicking to the dropdown sections - they become inactive:

[Here is the dropdown, which becomes inactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdLdF.png)

Here is the code for the dropdown:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <%= link_to 'All',  "#all", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab" %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <%= link_to 'Python',  "#python", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab" %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="<%= ''%>">
      <%= link_to "Algorithms", "#algorithms", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab"  %>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="<%= ''%>">
      <%= link_to "Web", "#web", role: "tab", :"data-toggle" => "tab"  %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And there is question: What classes, roles, data-toggles I must replace for correct working of bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it is that are you looking for.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="myTabDrop1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-controls="myTabDrop1-contents" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1" id="myTabDrop1-contents">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="all">All</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#python" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="python">Python</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#algorithms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="algorithms">Algorithms</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#web" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="web">Web</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content table-responsive" role="tablist">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="all">
        All tab content
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane " id="python">
      Python tab content
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="algorithms">
      Algorithms tab content
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="web">
      Web tab content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By removing 'role' and 'class' it loses its connection with logic written below the dropdown code.

Comment: @SakenSaipolla, I've updated the snippet to use native dropdown for tabs. Hope it will help

Comment: could you give some links or sources for filling the knowledge about this ? Because I scanned for the whole documentation from [Bootstrap components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns) but cannot find anything related with my problem

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs In the first example you can see the dropdown.